# Dynamo DB put_item fails silenty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using Lambda to write to dynamo (actually two dynamos) with the Table resource as specified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.html).

code flow is basically:

```
Step 1) Reads data from external source
Step 2) Do some cleaning and filtering
Step 3) Write data from Step 2 to first dynamo using comprehension
Step 4) Write data from Step 2 to second dynamo using comprehension
```

Both writing steps are done using the function below

```
def parse_response_from_dynamo(response:dict, entry:str):
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']!=200:
      print(f"Failed to write {entry}")
      return

def create_entry_in_dynamo(
    data:List[Dict], table_name:str)->None:
    """
    Write each dict in data to table_name in dynamo
    Input:
        data(List[Dict]): list of dicts, where each entry is the data
            to be sent to dynamo
        table_name(str): name of the table to which data will be written
    """

    dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamo.Table(table_name)

    [parse_response_from_dynamo(table.put_item(Item=item), item['id'])
           for item in data
    ]
```

Up until Step 3 works just fine, with all items being written to the first dynamo and I do see some activity in the AWS console. The problem is the Step 4 where I also am able to see write activity in the console, but the items don't appear in the table.
I found this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498647/boto3-put-item-succeeds-but-record-does-not-appear), confirming the consoles' graph I was supposed to inspect and I'm also way below 1k writes, 200 writes tops and very much rare.

Debug done so far:

- I believe comprehension to be the problem, so I used a regular for to inspect the responses and went up until 100 sequential writes for the same table. Worked normally
- Both tables are provisioned with 5 RCU/WCU and inspecting the first debug step, I consumed almost 2 WCU, so I don't believe the problem is here.
- Ran locally the code and Step 4 ran successfully (what I most found awkward)
- The AWS docs as well as the SO questions mentions the 1kb limit per partition. Reading from Items Summary after the manual successful write, the avg item size is of 42 bytes.

I read upon [error handling for dynamo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.SDKOverview.html), but I didn't received any error in any of the tests.

Can anybody shed a light here, please ?

Comment: When you say "comprehension", what are you referring to? I'm guessing a list comprehension. Anyhow, we can't help diagnose your code without ... your code.

Comment: List comprehension. I didn't change much of the aws documentation. I'll add the write part of the code. Sorry

Comment: This is an unusual way to use a list comprehension, but why don't you add more debug logging to `parse_response_from_dynamo` to help you understand what's going on. It will show you each put_item request/response so you can correlate that with what you think is going on.

Comment: BTW "fails silently" almost certainly means either "your code successfully put the item" or "your code didn't actually call put_item at all".

Comment: I tried adding more logs during the local execution and worked just fine, even when doubling the load to dynamo. On the `not called at all`, I find it hard to be the case, it's the same function called twice with nothing standing between the calls

Comment: Right, it's most likely that the code successfully wrote all the items. How are you determining that no writes were made to the 2nd table? You know that a put of an existing item will replace that item, I presume.

Comment: It replaces, yes. Inspecting the UI, from previous tests, there was very little delay between writing to dynamo and the item's appearance in the UI. I also waited about 5 minutes in an attempt.

p.s.: adding some more logs to the write. Tks for the suggestion